# Use of defer in Go

Tags: go

What is the use of `defer` in Go? The language documentation says it is executed when the surrounding function returns. Why not just put the code at end of given function?

Comment: `Why not just put the code at end of given function.` Because you could have multiple returns.

Comment: One use case: when you open a file you put a defer to make sure it closes in the end. Thus the open and close code is together and easier to read.

Comment: This one is the best article fully describing deferred functions in Go - https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-defer-simplified-77d3b2b817ff

Answer (score 101, accepted):

We usually use `defer` to close or deallocate resources.

A surrounding function executes all deferred function calls before it returns, even if it panics. If you just place a function call at the end of a surrounding function, it is skipped when panic happens.

Moreover a deferred function call can handle panic by calling the `recover` built-in function. This cannot be done by an ordinary function call at the end of a function.

Each deferred call is put on stack, and executed in reverse order when the surrounding function ends. The reversed order helps deallocate resources correctly.

The `defer` statement must be reached for a function to be called.

You can think of it as another way to implement `try-catch-finally` blocks.

Closing like `try-finally`:

```
func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("file")
    if err != nil {
        panic("cannot create file")
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // no matter what happens here file will be closed
    // for sake of simplicity I skip checking close result
    fmt.Fprintf(f,"hello")
}
```

Closing and panic handling like `try-catch-finally`

```
func main() {
    defer func() {
        msg := recover()
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }()
    f, err := os.Create(".") // . is a current directory
    if err != nil {
        panic("cannot create file")
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // no matter what happens here file will be closed
    // for sake of simplicity I skip checking close result
    fmt.Fprintf(f,"hello")
}
```

The benefit over try-catch-finally is that there is no nesting of blocks and variable scopes. This simplifies the structure of the surrounding function.

Just like finally blocks, deferred function calls can also modify the return value if they can reach the returned data.

```
func yes() (text string) {
    defer func() {
       text = "no"
    }()
    return "yes"
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(yes())
}
```

Comment: FWIW, "guaranteed" is a bit of a strong word to use here. Obviously there are scenarios where your deferred function will not run: for example, perhaps someone applies a shotgun to your CPU. More generally, perhaps the surrounding function never returns at all. I'd prefer to say that, before the surrounding function returns, it will execute all deferred functions.

Answer (score 31):

There are already good answers here. I would like to mention one more use case.

```
func BillCustomer(c *Customer) error {
    c.mutex.Lock()
    defer c.mutex.Unlock()

    if err := c.Bill(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := c.Notify(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // ... do more stuff ...

    return nil
}
```

The `defer` in this example ensures that no matter how `BillCustomer` returns, the `mutex` will be `unlocked` immediately prior to `BillCustomer` returning. This is extremely useful because without `defer` you would have to remember to `unlock` the `mutex` in every place that the function could possibly `return`.

[ref](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/when-to-use-defer-in-go).

Answer (score 7):

Well, it's not always guaranteed that your code may reach the end of the function (e.g. an error or some other condition may force you to return well ahead of the end of a function). The defer statement makes sure that whatever function is assigned to it gets executed for sure even if the function panics or the code returns well before the end of the function.

The defer statement also helps keep the code clean esp. in cases when there are multiple return statements in a function esp. when one needs to free resources before return (e.g. imagine you have an open call for accessing a resource at the beginning of the function  - for which a corresponding close must be called before the function returns for avoiding a resource leak. And say your function has multiple return statements, maybe for different conditions including error checking. In such a case, without defer, you normally would call close for that resource before each return statement). The defer statement makes sure the function you pass to it is always called irrespective of where the function returns, and thus saves you from extraenous housekeeping work.

Also defer can be called multiple times in the same function. E.g.: In case you have different resources being allocated through your function which need to be eventually freed before returning, then you can call defer for each of them after allocation and these functions are executed in the reverse order of the sequence in which they were called when the function exits.

Answer (score 4):

Key benefit of using `defer` - it will be called any way no matter how function will return. If an extraordinary situation would occur deferred function will be called.

So it gives nice things:

1. Recover after `panic`. This allows yes realize `try ... catch` behavior.
2. Not to forget clean up (close files, free memory, etc) before normal exit. You may open some resource and you have to close it before exit. But function can have several exit points - so you have to add freeing in *every* return point. That’s very tedious in maintenance. Or you can put only one deferred statement  - and resources will be released automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Summary:

When we do certain operations that need cleanup, we can "schedule" the cleanup operations which would be run when the function returns no matter which path that happens, including due to panic.

Detailed answer:

1. Programming languages strive to provide constructs that facilitate simpler and less error-prone development. (E.g. why should Golang support garbage collection when we can free the memory ourselves)
2. A function can return at multiple points. The user might overlook doing certain cleanup operations in some paths
3. Some cleanup operations are not relevant in all return paths
4. Also, it is better to keep the cleanup code closer to the original operation which needed the cleanup
5. When we do certain operations that need cleanup, we can "schedule" the cleanup operations which would be run when the function returns no matter which path that happens.

Answer (score 0):

> A `defer` statement defers the execution of a function until the
>   surrounding function returns.

This example demonstrates `defer` functionality:

```
func elapsed(what string) func() {
    start := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("start")
    return func() {
        fmt.Printf("%s took %v\n", what, time.Since(start))
    }
}

func main() {
    defer elapsed("page")()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
}
```

Out:

```
start
page took 3s
```

Comment: The question wasn't "how does defer work?" The question was "why do I want it?"